# Jealstic environment variable as string?

Tags: environment-variables, devops, jelastic

I'm new to jelastic and find this app really cool.

It takes times, but for now i've manged to add all my environments variables from the dashboard.

There is only one variable that is not accepted.

This variable look like this `121345648975423165498134654231`, but this variable is not a number but needs to be a string.

As there is no char in this variable, the env is added as a number. The app then crash beacause the number is to big to be contained in a Number format.

So my question is how can i pass my env variable as a string in jelastic ?
I've tried with `"121345648975423165498134654231"`. Jelastic take my var as a string but with the " " at the begining and the end and this make my backend crash.

I need jelastic to see this var as a string, how can i add it ?

Thank you for your help.

12.02.2020 Edit:

[image]

This is where i try to ass my variable, i click on "Ajouter (Add)" button, then enter my variable and click apply on the bottom right of the screen.

And then i got this unknown error with a "send report" button.

[image]

Ps: this is not my real client id but the length is the same.

Comment: Environment variables are not typed. Please edit the question to include your code where you make use of the variable - most likely the problem could be solved by casting at that point?

Comment: Did you try to set variable via the dashboard or via another panel?

In which way did you set this variable (if it was via API, then please provide which API exactly was applied)

If via Cloudscripting then please send us how the manifest looks like?

Could you please provide reproduced steps or if it possible some screenshots where you tried to use such variable?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Damien - Lyershift && @Jelastic, I've set them via the dashboard. As shown in my edit.

Comment: The corresponding bug "JE-54844" has been registered. It will be fixed in the next Jelastic 5.9-2 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my tests, it looks like a bug - Jelastic only accepts an integer env variable up to 20 digits. Attempts to set 21+ digits results in a dashboard error.

Alphanumeric strings are not affected (can be longer).

I suggest to report this problem to your hosting provider's support team so that it can be fixed, and if essential for you (and if possible) they might be able to provide you with a workaround in the meantime.

For example, the API method is not affected, so if you absolutely must set an environment variable with 21+ digits right now, you could use the [AddContainerEnvVars API method](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Control-method-AddContainerEnvVars) to do that successfully (remember to URL encode the JSON key:value pairs).

**EDIT:** Jelastic confirmed this behaviour is caused by a platform bug (JE-54844) expected to be fixed in Jelastic 5.9-2

Comment: For Info: The Platform from my web service provider was updated to 5.9-2, but nothing is fixed.